# I have a problem in Unreal Engine 5.3.2 but i don't know what's error

Tags: packaging, unreal-engine5

i can't Package Project
Note that I downloaded the SDK and put hostfxr.dll in Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.3\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\AutomationTool

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpNmb.png)

I'm so tired and I hope you know the solution